# javascript location

Tags: javascript, location

This checks "if we are on `movies.php` page":

```
if (location.href.match(/movies.php/)) {
// something happens
}
```

how to **add for this** (like `or`) "if we are on `music.php` page"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to see if you are on `movies.php` or on `music.php`? Meaning you want to do the same thing if you are on either?

```
if (location.href.match(/movies\.php/) || location.href.match(/music\.php/)) {
// something happens
}
```

Or if you want to do something different, you can use an `else if`

```
if (location.href.match(/movies\.php/)) {
// something happens
}

else if(location.href.match(/music\.php/)) {
// something else happens
}
```

Also, instead of using `match` you can use `test`:

```
if (/movies\.php/.test(location.href) || /music\.php/.test(location.href)) {
// something happens
}
```

Based on paulj's answer, you can refine the regular expressions in `if` statement that checks to see if you are on either page, to a single regular expression:

```
/(music|movies)\.php/
```

Answer (score 1):

How about ..

```
if (/(movies\.php|music\.php)/.test(location.href)) {
// Do something
}
```

Or even better...

```
if (/(movies|music)\.php/).test(location.href)) {
// Do something
}
```

Note the \., this literally matches "a single period" where as in regex . matches any character, thus these are true, but probably not what you want...

```
if (/movies.php/.test('movies_php')) alert(0);
if (/movies.php/.test('movies/php')) alert(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following improves on previous answers in a couple ways ...

```
if (/(movies|music)\.php$/.test(location.pathname)) {
    var pageName = RegExp.$1; // Will be either 'music' or 'movies'
}
```

- Provides the name of the page (sans .php extension) via the RegExp.$1 property
- Using location.pathname eliminates extraneous hits on possible query parameters (e.g. "...?redirect=music.php")
- Use of regex '|' operator combines tests into a single regex (particularly good if you have lots of pages you want to match)
- Use of regex '$' operator constrains match to end of pathname (avoids extraneous hits in the middle of a path. Not very likely in your example, but good practice)